Multithreaded Red-Black Gauss Seidel running slow
I'm very new to multithreading and I've been trying to multithread the incompressibility step in my PIC/FLIP fluid simulation in C++ for a while using the  library. The best way I've found is to divide the grid up horizontally n times for n threads, and then do two passes over the grid to solve the incompressibility using red-black gauss seidel. I'm using the same thread pool that pezza's work used in his video which was able to run a huge amount of objects at 60 fps, so I don't think that the problem is with the thread pool, but rather how I'm using it. Here's the method which I am multithreading:
void solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForColumns(const float dt, const float overRelaxation, const int startColumn, const int endColumn, const bool red) {
    int n = this->numY;
    for (int i = startColumn; i < endColumn; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < numY - 1; ++j) {
            if (red) { 
                if ((i + j) % 2 != 0) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (!red) { 
                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
            } 
            if (this->cellType[i * n + j] == FLUID_CELL) {
                float leftType = cellType[(i - 1) * n + j] <= AIR_CELL ? 1: 0;
                float rightType = cellType[(i + 1) * n + j] <= AIR_CELL ? 1: 0;
                float topType = cellType[i * n + j - 1] <= AIR_CELL ? 1 : 0;
                float bottomType = cellType[i * n + j + 1] <= AIR_CELL ? 1: 0;
                float divideBy = leftType + rightType + topType + bottomType;
                if (divideBy != 0.f) {
                    float divergence;
                    divergence = this->u[(i + 1) * n + j] - this->u[i * n + j]+ this->v[i * n + j + 1] - this->v[i * n + j];
                    if (this->particleRestDensity > 0.f) {
                        float k = 10.f; // 3, 10
                        float compression = this->particleDensity[i * n + j] -this->particleRestDensity;
                        if (compression > 0.f) {
                            divergence = divergence - k * compression;
                        }
                    }
                    float p = divergence / divideBy;
                    p *= overRelaxation;
                    this->u[i * n + j] += leftType * p;
                    this->u[(i + 1) * n + j] -= rightType * p;
                    this->v[i * n + j] += topType * p;
                    this->v[i * n + j + 1] -= bottomType * p;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

which basically just does some math to make certain cells of the grid incompressible. And here's the actual multithreaded part of the code which executes this method:
for (int _ = 0; _ < 10; ++_) { 

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
        if (i != numThreads - 1) {
            thread_pool.addTask([&, this, i]() {
                this->solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows(sdtoverRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i*numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + 1, true);
            });
        }
        else {
            thread_pool.addTask([&, this, i]() {
                this->solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows(sdtoverRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i*numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + numMissedRows + 1, true);
            });
        }
    }
    thread_pool.waitForCompletion();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
        if (i != numThreads - 1) {
            thread_pool.addTask([&, this, i]() {
                this->solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows(sdtoverRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i*numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + 1, false);
            });
        }
        else {
            thread_pool.addTask([&, this, i]() {
                this->solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows(sdt, overRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i * numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + numMissedRows + 1, false);
            });
        }
    }
    thread_pool.waitForCompletion();
}

I thought that it was running slow because of the overhead from the threads joining, but when i run this on larger and larger grids with the same amount of threads, the time taken per frame decreases much more rapidly than a single threaded program on the same size grids. I would expect for the multithreaded code to at least scale well, but it doesn't at all. I also don't think that it's because I'm dispatching and joining the threads in a loop 10 times, because in pezza's video he dispatches and joins threads 8 times per frame (but again I know very little about multithreading).
Edit
Here is a not very minimal but reproducible example that compares a single thread versus ten threads modifying lists based on the incompressibility step. I don't use the thread pool but rather just barebone threads. I don't think that should change much though:
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows(const float  overRelaxation, const int startColumn, const int endColumn, const bool red, const int gridHeight, std::vector<float>& u, std::vector<float>& v) {
    int n = gridHeight;
    for (int i = startColumn; i < endColumn; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; ++j) {
        
            if (red) { 
                if ((i + j) % 2 != 0) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (!red) { 
                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
            } 
            float leftType = 1;
            float rightType = 1;
            float topType = 1;
            float bottomType = 1;
            float divideBy = 4;
            if (divideBy != 0.f) {
                float divergence;
                divergence = u[(i + 1) * n + j] - u[i * n + j] + v[i * n + j + 1] - v[i * n + j];
                float p = divergence / divideBy;
                p *= overRelaxation;
                u[i * n + j] += leftType * p;
                u[(i + 1) * n + j] -= rightType * p;
                v[i * n + j] += topType * p;
                v[i * n + j + 1] -= bottomType * p;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int gridHeight = 100;
    int gridWidth = 100;
    std::vector<float> u(gridHeight * gridWidth, 10);
    std::vector<float> v(gridHeight * gridWidth, 10);

    int numThreads = 10;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    float overRelaxation = 1.9;
    int numRowsEachThread = (gridWidth - 2) / numThreads;
    int numMissedRows = (gridWidth - 2) - numRowsEachThread * numThreads;

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // main loop to run the incompressibility stuff
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
            if (i != numThreads - 1) {
                threads.push_back(std::thread(solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows, overRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i *numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + 1, true, gridHeight,  std::ref(u), std::ref(v)));
            }
            else {
                threads.push_back(std::thread(
                    solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows, overRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i *numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + numMissedRows+ 1, true, gridHeight,  std::ref(u), std::ref(v)));
            }
        }
        
        for (auto& thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }

        threads.clear();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
            if (i != numThreads - 1) {
                threads.push_back(std::thread(
                    solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows, overRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i *numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + 1, false, gridHeight,  std::ref(u), std::ref(v)));
            }
            else {
                threads.push_back(std::thread(
                    solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows, overRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i *numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + numMissedRows+ 1, false, gridHeight,  std::ref(u), std::ref(v)));
            }
        }
            
        for (auto& thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }

        threads.clear();
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);

    std::cout << "Time taken for 10 threads: " << duration.count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

    // single threaded program to compare
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
            if (i != numThreads - 1) {
                solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows(overRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i *numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + 1, true, gridHeight,  std::ref(u), std::ref(v));
            }
            else {
                solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows(overRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i *numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + numMissedRows+ 1, true, gridHeight,  std::ref(u), std::ref(v));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
            if (i != numThreads - 1) {
                solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows(overRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i *numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + 1, false, gridHeight,  std::ref(u), std::ref(v));
            }
            else {
                solveIncompressibilityRedBlackForRows(overRelaxation, i * numRowsEachThread + 1, i *numRowsEachThread + numRowsEachThread + numMissedRows+ 1, false, gridHeight,  std::ref(u), std::ref(v));
            }
        }
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);

    std::cout << "Time taken for single thread: " << duration.count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}

running this, I got:
Time taken for 10 threads: 46613 milliseconds
Time taken for single thread: 226 milliseconds

Just curious, did you use a Fortran implementation as a guide for writing your routine?  Your threading generally partitions the problem okay, however, the memory access patterns in your data likely causes a lot of cache-line contention.
Fortran stores data column major, while C/C++ use row major.  Your top loops that go across a set of columns, with the inner loop going down each column uses cache lines very inefficiently.
Try swapping your top-level i and j loops, and see if that makes things go faster.

Please write a [mcve] that people can copy and paste and hit run, it is hard to judge where the slowdown is coming from by just inspecting a part of the code.

If your memory access patterns are very bad then you could be memory bound, which is hard to work around except by improving memory access patterns as pointed above

How do you measure?

@radical7 I tried switching the loop order but unfortunately did not see any speedup

@n.m.couldbeanAI I just ran the entire simulation, changing the grid granularity, running less and less course grids multiple times and seeing the average delta time of the simulation once it ended. I will also provide a minimum reproducible example in a bit within my main question through an edit.

@AhmedAEK I included a minimal reproducible example in an edit at the bottom of my post.

It's not possible for me to analyze this fully ATM, but those times suggest that there's something wrong with the way you break up the task. Have you verified that you do the same number of total iterations in both the single and multi-threaded scenarios?

here is a modified version with slightly less OS threads spawning (which are super expensive to spawn) https://godbolt.org/z/hbabqYG8P , if you remove the barrier you will find that the multithreaded version is faster, the problem here is that each thread is doing simple mathematics over 50 doubles .... that takes the computer like a few hundred nanoseconds, and you are wasting over 50 microseconds synchronizing per iteration ... you really need like a 100 times bigger grid to start seeing a difference, each thread should have over 1000 grid elements to work with.

on my 4 core potato if you increase the grid size to 1000x1000 then the multithreaded version is 4 times faster than the single threaded one, proving my point, the number of threads needs to be such that each thread has at least 1000 grid elements to work with, preferably closer to 10,000 grid elements, and you need faster synchronization primitives

you cannot have the threads locking a mutex on each iteration to obtain their task, that would be super slow, instead have a semaphore that the main thread increments by the thread count on each iteration, that would give you more control than the barrier, in short, you are wasting too much time synchronizing a lot more threads than you actually need for a given problem size using slow synchronization primitives

on the other side, to have threads notify the main thread that they have finished the iteration, have another semaphore that each thread increments and the main thread will decrement it by the threads count, this way the main thread will know when all threads have finished the iteration without using mutexes, you need to avoid mutexes if you plan on having more than 4 threads, because mutexes don't scale well

Thank all of you for the help, you all have led to to understand multithreading a lot better. I would need a grid much too large to run in real time for my method of multithreading to work faster than a single thread. I'm gonna try my luck with multithreading the collision detection in my simulation as I just don't think it is possible to make multithreading more efficient within the incompressibility method for what I am trying to do.

I wanted to ask how do you measure specifically the (delta) time?

heres how i calculate dt within the simulation (in sfml):
while (window.isOpen())
{
sf::Time deltaTime = deltaClock.restart();
float dt = deltaTime.asSeconds();
numFrames++;
totalDT += dt;
if (close simulation) {
std::cout << totalDT / numFrames;
i just see the deltaTime of each loop
